# How to show all values from a column in a table, in a textbox when a button is pressed?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a query which displays, into a textbox, only ONE value from a column in a table. How can i modify the code to show ALL the corresponding values from the column? I also have a drop down list where the information is selected from. Here is the code:

```
        string selected = "SELECT Aname FROM Pet WHERE Species = '" + DropSpecies1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";

        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(selected, myConnection);

        try
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader myreader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (myreader.Read())
            {

                String animal = myreader["AName"].ToString();
                TextBox2.Text = animal;
            }


        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Exception in DBHandler" + ex;
        }
        finally
        {

            myConnection.Close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Define all corresponding values

Comment: How do you want to show all the values in one textbox? Do you want them comma separated then display them or what?

Comment: show the output you want. It will be easier to unserstand

Comment: Basically, within the column there are multiple names, and the query only returns the last name from the column.

Comment: @user3076157 - This because of `TextBox2.Text = animal;` will override the textbox value each time with the current vaule from the loop. You have to do `TextBox2.Text += animal; + ","` for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `+=`.  Using `=` will keep changing the text until it gets to the last one and only the last will end up displaying.

```
TextBox2.Text += animal + " ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use parametrized queries to prevent sql-injection and you can fill a `List<string>` in the loop, then use `ToArray` to create a `string[]` which you can assign to the `TextBox`' `Lines` property or via `TextBox2.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, animals)`:

```
string sql = "SELECT Aname FROM Pet WHERE Species = @Species;";
using(var myConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Connection-String"))
using (var myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, myConnection))
{
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Species", DropSpecies1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    try {
        myConnection.Open();
        List<string> animals = new List<string>();
        using (var rd = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rd.Read())
                animals.Add(rd.GetString(0));
        }
        TextBox2.Lines = animals.ToArray();  
        // or via String.Join:
        TextBox2.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, animals);              
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Exception in DBHandler" + ex.ToString();
    }
}
```